# php проверить что в строке только буквы и цифры

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть такая строка `Всем привет 123` – это правильная.

Есть еще такая строка `Hello world 78` – это тоже правильная строка.

А еще есть такая строка `Как дела //` – это уже неправильная строка.

Все эти строки записываются в переменную например `$text`.

Как с помощью `preg_match` проверить переменную `$text` на наличие там латинских или русских букв и цифр?

Рылся в интернете и собрал вот такое, но оно не работает.

```
preg_match('/[a-z0-9]+/i',$text)
```

Помогите составить выражение.

Comment: ctype_alnum(), но не знаю как оно ведет себя с пробелами.

Comment: [`preg_match('/^[a-zа-яё]+\h+[a-zа-яё]+\h+\d+$/ui',$text)`](https://regex101.com/r/fV6qC6/1)

Comment: А так не проще будет?
[$iswrong = preg_match('/[^\d\w\s]+/iu',$text);](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7bb772078d15cd935cec94d292b8cf88028eb505)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
preg_match("/^[a-zа-яё\d]{1}[a-zа-яё\d\s]*[a-zа-яё\d]{1}$/i", $text);
```

Поясняю, что здесь написано:

1. `^` - начало строки
2. `[a-zа-яё\d]{1}` - строка может начинаться с букв латинского или русского языка (`a-zа-яё`) или цифры (`\d`). Один из этих символов должен обязательно встречаться `{1}` раз. Группа символов заключается в `[` и `]`.
3. `[a-zа-яё\d\s]*` - то же самое, что в предыдущем случае, но добавляем еще любой пробельный символ (пробел, перевод строки, табуляция). Один их этих символов может встречаться произвольное число раз, 0 или больше, это и означает знак `*`.
4. `[a-zа-яё\d]{1}` - какой символ должен находиться непосредственно перед концом строки.
5. `$` - собственно, конец строки.
6. Все это заключено в специальные ограничители (разделители). Ими может быть любой символ. Лучше использовать именно слеш. `/здесь регулярное выражение/`
7. `i` - означает, что регулярное выражение нечувствительно к регистру. Указывается сразу после ограничителя и называется флагом.

Полезные ссылки:

1. [Статья о регулярных выражениях.](http://www.php.su/articles/?cat=regexp&page=006)
2. [Принцип работы функции preg_match](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match.php)

Comment: Спасибо за подробное пояснения, я даже сохранил его у себя на компьютере

Comment: Но сделал я все таки так 
if (preg_match("/[^(\w)|(\x7F-\xFF)|(\s)]/",$text)) 
{
echo  "Имя может содержать только русс. / лат. символы, пробел, цифры и знак _";
}

Comment: когда понимаешь смысл - писать код одно удовольствие ;)

Comment: @Razzwan, юникод уже отменили? И `{1}` лишние тут.

Comment: @Visman, можете поправить - напишите правильно. Я не знаю, что нужно изменить, чтоб стало правильно и почему.

Answer (score 3):

В php уже есть функция, которая это делает.

```
bool ctype_alnum ( string $text )
```

Более подробная информация о функции по [ссылке](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.ctype-alnum.php).

Answer (score 1):

Ответ который я искал

```
if (preg_match("/[^(\w)|(\x7F-\xFF)|(\s)]/",$text)) 
{
echo "Имя может содержать только русские / латинские символы, пробел, цифры и знак _";
}
else
{
echo "Этот заголовок - $text нормальный";   
}
```